Sorting a large number of core data entities
I have a Song entity in Core data and each of them has an index attribute of type integer. I am expecting a large number of song entities in the range of 10k to 100k and want to maintain order.
The issue is if a user adds a new song entity in the middle of the ordered songs, I have to update the indices of all subsequent entities which is very slow using fetch request and then updating.
Is it advisable to use an index attribute of type double instead so I could just assign an index that is half of the previous and next items (e.g. assign an index of 1.5 for inserting a song between index 1 and 2)?
Is sorting based on double values performant?
extension Song {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Song> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Song>(entityName: "Song")
    }
    
    @NSManaged public var album: String?
    @NSManaged public var artist: String?
    @NSManaged public var fileExtension: String?
    @NSManaged public var genre: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var playlistId: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var index: Int //Used to order song entities
}


I would make an entity for Album, than you can fetch all the songs of an individual album and update them.

Does this answer your question? How to handle many entities in managed object context and save them to disk only when necessary?

What's the motivation of wanting to keep 10k-100k+ songs in a specific order? Is this for a playlist? Or are you wanting to keep them in order based on some property of the track such as date added or last modified?
Based on your description it sounds like you're trying to create a playlist, which raises some more questions in terms of user experience when managing 100k+ items.
The easiest answer is to limit the size of a playlist to some reasonable number (e.g. maybe 1000 or 10,000 depending). But this doesn't solve your question as stated.
So, for the sake of this question, I will ignore the concerns and assume you are trying to build a playlist of 100k+ items.

Addressing your questions:

I have to update the indices of all subsequent entities which is very slow using fetch request and then updating.

You're right that requiring an insertion to cause cascading modifications to upwards of O(n) items's indices in the database would be not great in terms of performance.
Ideally, insertions into a list only require modifying the record being inserted. Ordering is then a side effect managed by the database.

Is it advisable to use an index attribute of type double instead?

Using a double will introduce more problems than it solves because you'll then be dealing with floating point precision issues. But you're on to the right path.

One approach would be to use a linked list, where each Song gets an additional property of previousID and nextID. Moving an item in the playlist would be essentially O(c) because you'd only have to modify 3 items. The downside to this approach is that you no longer have an efficient way to load all of your items into memory; loading a list of Songs will require loading one song at a time, then fetching the subsequent Song, and so on.
But let's hold that thought.

Another approach is to introduce a lightweight tree structure.
Instead of using a single playlist index for each item, you can introduce a second field which is a playlist "page". Playlist pages will have the following rules:

Each page will have a UUID.
Each page has a max size. Let's pick 100 as a starting point, but you'll likely want to tune this as you get a better sense of the performance characteristics.
Song index properties are valid only within the page they are contained.
Moving an item within a page will adjust the necessary Songs' index properties within that page. This will only require updating O(pagesize) items and, because pagesize is pretty small, this is pretty cheap (comparatively).

Alternatively you could store a list of UUIDs as part of the Page structure. This requires more storage but requires fewer record modifications.


Each Page will have a reference to the set of Songs contained within it, allowing for efficient loads of sorted page Songs.
Each Page will have a link to its previous and next pages, which allows you to introduce new Page instance between two Pages if a Page gets too large.

extension Page {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Page> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Page>(entityName: "Page")
    }
    
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var songs: [Song]
    @NSManaged public var previousPage: Page?
    @NSManaged public var nextPage: Page?
}


In that case it’s not really important to keep the entire set in order. From the user’s perspective they’re only going to care that the next N number of playing items is predictable, after that you can pull items essentially at random (as long as they haven’t been recently played).

I mentioned the downside to that in the answer above:

The downside to this approach is that you no longer have an efficient way to load all of your items into memory; loading a list of Songs will require loading one song at a time, then fetching the subsequent Song, and so on.

